# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'wipetouch'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to integrate the wipetouch plugin into my portfolio http://www.i-jp.nl, for now without success.

Chrome gives me the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'wipetouch'

I can't figure out the problem. Here is the code which calls wipetouch, this is located in slider.js:

```
$(document).wipetouch({
                wipeLeft: function(result) { 
                    //if (slide >= 0 && slide < 3){
                        //$(".slider").animate({"right": "+=320px"}, "slow");
                        //slide = slide + 1;
                    //};
                    alert('test');
                },
            });
```

Comment: are you including the plugin at all? ie: `<script type="text/javascript" src="(wipetouch.js)"></script>`.

Comment: The problem is that you are loading **two** different jQuery versions, `1.8.0` and `1.7.2`. The plugin attaches to `jQuery.fn` which is the `1.7.2` version, not `$`. Is see that the later included version (`1.7.2`) calls `jQuery.noConflict();`, which reverts the `$` to point to the earlier included version. Why are you loading jQuery twice?

Comment: yes the plugin is called just before the </body> tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have jQuery loading twice. This is causing the problem with the `wipetouch` method not being available.

As for a fix. I would **try removing the second jQuery file reference you have in your code**.

Here is some more information courtesy of Felix Kling:

> The problem is that you are loading two different jQuery versions, `1.8.0` and `1.7.2`. The plugin attaches to `jQuery.fn` which is the `1.7.2` version, not `$`. Is see that the later included version (`1.7.2`) calls `jQuery.noConflict();`, which reverts the `$` to point to the earlier included version.

You are first loading jQuery on line 11:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

Then again on line 18:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://i-jp.nl/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.2'></script>
```

Comment: The plugin is definitely loaded.

Comment: @FelixKling When i look in the scripts in firebug it is not loaded for me, thats weird.

Comment: @FelixKling I updated my answer and removed the part about this script not being loaded

Comment: @FelixKling Would you be ok with me including your comment in my answer?

Comment: i know i load it in the head myself, but can you tell me where the plugin calls the other version?